# Group By the overlapping value ranges

Tags: javascript

I have a table products with the next stucture

```
id | product | product_type | min_price | max_price
 1 | bag     | homeware     | 1         | 20
 2 | pen     | homeware     | 1         | 4
 3 | teapot  | homeware     | 16        | 20
 4 | cherry  | grocery      | 4         | 16
 5 | juice   | grocery      | 4         | 16
 6 | chicken | grocery      | 6         | 16
 7 | pie     | bakery       | 8         | 16
 8 | cake    | bakery       | 16        | 20
```

I need to group them in the overlapping price ranges. If new product is in or out of the range - the new one get formed

For example:

```
[
  range1: {min: 1, max: 4, products: [bag, pen]},
  range2: {min: 4, max: 6, products: [bag, cherry, juice]},
  range3: {min: 6, max: 8, products: [bag, cherry, juice, chicken]},
  range4: {min: 8, max: 16, products: [bag, cherry, juice, chicken, pie]},
  range5: {min: 16, max: 20, products: [bag, teapot, cake]}
]
```

Comment: What did you try exactly?

Comment: Please post your code to show your attempt to solve the problem and point out what isn't working or any error you received.

Comment: @AluanHaddad have the overlapping price ranges groups, it might be solvable as weill with sql

Comment: Well, I'm sure it could be depending on the implementation, but you posted the question under JavaScript. Since you know what your resulting JS object should look like (minus syntax errors), it seems quite doable. Gibe it a shot and if you get stuck ask a specific question based on your implementation so far.